# 64-bit architecture vs 32-bit arcitecture

Tags: architecture

Why some people think that 64-bit architectures are no better than 32-bit architectures unless the computer has more than 4 GB RAM? What is so particular about 4 GB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because they don't understand the other advantages of x86 64-bit operating systems such as effectively unlimited virtual memory and additional general-purpose registers.

The reason 4GB is a "magic number" is that without PAE, 32-bit x86 operating systems can't address more than 4GB of physical memory. Even with PAE, processes running on 32-bit x86 operating systems can't address more than 4GB of virtual memory at a time (and typically only 2GB or 3GB) which is more of a problem if you have that much physical memory.

Also, under comparable conditions, a 64-bit operating system running 64-bit applications will need more memory than a 32-bit operating system running 32-bit applications. With 2GB or less, this can be a significant disadvantage of 64-bit operating systems. With 3GB-4GB, it can cancel out the advantages of a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, A computer with a 32-bit architecture system, then the system is intended to handle data in 32-bits. It means that the CPU can process 32-bit data in single execution. And Memory addresses in a 32-bit architecture are also 32-bits long, as a result this is limiting the addressable memory, (2^32 ~ 4.29 X 10^9) and it is equal to 4GB. This is the reason why 32-bit architecture not able to access more than 4GB of RAM.

On the other hand 64-bit architecture allows computer to work with 64-bit data in a single execution, which results in advantages like, Increased addressable memory and improved performance.

Answer (score -1):

32bits cannot access more than 4GB of ram.  So any ram above that is useless, with a 32 bit architecture.